# What is a word for "conception of truth"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

Is there a Latin word for "conception of truth" or "notion of truth" or a hybrid Graeco-Latin word for it? If not can such a word be termed or constructed for it? Or a phrase? How is it best translated?

I want to use it as "the conception/notion of truth of different cultures in different cultures is so....so...." I want to use the term as a meta-category of the way different people, civilisations, groups think about truth.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific by what you mean by "conception of truth"? Maybe provide a few example sentences so we get a sense of how you want to use it?

Comment: @cmw I want to use it as "the conception/notion of truth of different cultures in different cultures is so....so...." I wan to use the term as a meta-category of the way different ppl, civilisations, groups think of truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any single word that would mean that, but it can be easily expressed in Latin.

The word *[cognitio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=cognitio&la=la#lexicon)* in certain contexts means:

> A conception, notion, idea

This combined with the genitive form of *[veritas](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=veritatis&la=la#lexicon)* gives:

> *cognitio veritatis*

Answer (score 2):

I think that Expedito Bipes's answer is spot on, but as is usual with Latin, there is more than one way to say it.

*Sententia veritatis* is another way to say it. It perhaps carries a slightly different connotation, leaning a little closer to "opinion of the truth", and maybe not as close to "understanding of the truth" as *cognitio veritatis*.

I'd also like to note that *verum*, literally, "a true thing", can also be used to mean "truth". So *cognitio veri* and *sententia veri* are also alternatives.

Another note worth mentioning is an idiom peculiar to Latin (as opposed to English) in that an abstract noun of a verb can often be replaced by a participle. So *verum cognitum* or *verum sensum* can be understood to mean the truth *as* conceived or the truth *as*  learnt. If you go this route, you'll need to rely on context to tell whether *verum cognitum* means "conception of the truth" or "a truth conceived".